# Migrating domain from WordPress to Heroku

Tags: wordpress, heroku, dns, subdomain, web-hosting

I'm trying to connect a domain I bought through WordPress to a new site I'm hosting on Heroku.

I tried to follow the Heroku docs on custom domains but now I'm lost: [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) sends me to my new Heroku site, but mywebsite.com still directs me to the old WordPress.

What I've done already:

On wordpress, I initiated a domain transfer and received a transfer code (which I haven't figured out what to do with).

Then I ran on the command line

```
heroku domains:add www.mywebsite.com
heroku domains
```

...which showed me a xxxx.herokudns.com address

Finally I went back to WordPress.com and created a new CNAME record, as the Heroku docs specified

Type: CNAME
Name: [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)
Alias of: xxxx.herokudns.com

This is, I understand from the Heroku docs, the process to register a subdomain. I was unable to follow the procedure for a custom root domain as WordPress does not allow for ALIAS or ANAME records, and requires a subdomain for CNAMES. I also was unable to follow the procedure for a custom wildcard domain because the command failed on the command line

```
zsh: no matches found: *.mywebsite.com
```

Help! How do I make sure that users who don't enter the www before mywebsite.com arrive at the right site??

Comment: You need to use an A record for `mysite.com` or create a redirect from `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com`. https://wordpress.com/support/move-domain/setting-custom-a-records/

Comment: what is the `zsh` comand that fails?

Comment: @seb-2020 did you ever figure this out?